# $\Bbb Q \subseteq \Bbb Q(\sqrt {a + \sqrt b})$ is normal iff at least one of $a^2 − b$ and $(a^2 − b)/b$ is a square in $ \Bbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions

> Let $a, b$  be integers such that $b$ is not a square. Show that the field extension $\Bbb Q \subseteq \Bbb Q(\sqrt {a + \sqrt b})$ is normal if and only if at least one of $a^2 − b$ and $(a^2 − b)/b$ is a square in $\Bbb Q$.
> [Hint: Consider the normal closure of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt {a + \sqrt b})$ over $\Bbb Q$ as a field extension of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt b)$.]

($\implies$)
My try:

Let $a; b$ be integers such that $b$ is not a square. if $a^2 − b$  is a square in   $ \Bbb Q$.,  then the field extension $\Bbb Q \subseteq \Bbb Q(\sqrt {a + \sqrt b})$ is normal.

If $a^2 − b$  is a square in   $ \Bbb Q$, it means $\sqrt {a^2 − b} \in \Bbb Q$.

I can write    $\sqrt {a^2 − b}=\sqrt {a+\sqrt b}\sqrt {a-\sqrt b}$

then $\sqrt {a − \sqrt b}= \frac{\sqrt {a^2 − b}} {\sqrt {a + \sqrt b}}\in \Bbb Q(\sqrt {a + \sqrt b})$ which  is the splitting field of $f(x)=(t^2-a)^2-b$, so this extension is normal.

Similarly I showed that if  $(a^2 − b)/b$ is a square, the extension is normal

**I am stuck trying to show the converse. How should I do that?**

Comment: For context, see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4802847/b-not-a-square-a2-%e2%88%92-b-a-square-why-is-bbb-q-sqrt-a-sqrt-b-the-sp?rq=1). You can find this also on MSE.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367383/determine-the-galois-group-of-mathbbq-sqrtab-sqrtd) might be of use.